# Can you install an SSL certificate on a server other than where the CSR was generated?

Tags: powershell, ssl, automation, cryptography, ssl-certificate

I have recently been tasked with automating our certificate issuance/renewal process via PowerShell. Having never worked in this space prior, I'm doing a lot of on the fly learning.

The idea is to make the execution stateless, meaning we can have one server running a script that requests certificates and simply store them to be installed on the appropriate machines later. That will likely be automated as well. My question is this: when I generate a CSR on the server, and the certificate is ultimately issued by DigiCert, can that certificate only be installed on that server? My research says yes, and yet I tested this by installing an already issued certificate on my local machine and it worked. I had not generated the CSR for that certificate on my machine, yet I was able to install it without error. Would the problems only come in when binding the certificate to a site?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can install the certificate anywhere, on as many things as you want, as long as you have the private key + certificate response from DigiCert. Typically in Windows land that means exporting the certificate and the private key to a .pfx file with a password. If you just import the certificate on another machine and not the private key, it won't be able to work properly. Technically, you can do it, that is; I believe some certificate authorities try to charge you more for the right/license to use the same certificate on more systems, and I don't know the status of that.

Comment: Your question would be more on topic for [sf] or [su] as at this stage it is not really related to programming. As for the question itself @TessellatingHeckler already replied in a comment... To convince you, imagine another setup: a big hosting company having multiple servers handling the same names. Obviously the certificates are shared among all servers, as is the key (not the only way to do it, but a simple way), so the certificate whn issued + associated key can be freely copied anywhere you need, at the technical level.

Comment: Thank you both for the comments and explanations!